# Prove that the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}a^n \frac{logn}{n^2}$ is convergent only for $[-1,1]$ and divergent elsewhere.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Prove that the series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}a^n \frac{logn}{n^2}$ is convergent only for $a \epsilon [-1,1]$and divergent elsewhere.

I have given it an honest attempt, I can see why this must be true graphically and I have established convergence on $[-1,1]$, But I am having troubles establishing the divergence part.

Comment: Apply the ratio test

Comment: You can see it must be true graphically?

Comment: @Dr.MV Ratio test to prove divergence? Could you also comment on the correctness of the question. Thanks

Comment: @zhw, What i meant to say was if you draw the graph of $n^2$ and $log n$ it gives a hint as to why the series might be convergent for a in [-1,1].

Comment: @spaceman_spiff Yes, the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test) to prove divergence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying the $\;n\,-$ th root test (Cauchy-Hadamard):

$$\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{\log n}{n^2}\right|}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\implies\;\text{the convergence radius is}\;\;R=1$$

and thus the series converges for $\;|a|<1\;$, yet at the extreme points $\;a=\pm1\;$ we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log n}{n^2}\;,\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\log n}{n^2}$$

and both series converge because the second one converges absolutely as it is a Leibniz series and, for example, $\;\log n\le n^{1/2}\implies \dfrac{\log n}{n^2}\le\dfrac1{n^{3/2}}\;$ (the series is positive for $\;n\ge3\;$) .

You already knew this.

Now, for $\;a>1\;$ we can write $\;a=1+h\;,\;\;h>0\;$ (for $\;a<-1\;$ it is similar), so

$$a^n=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nkh^k\ge1+nh\implies a^n\frac{\log n}{n^2}\ge\frac{\log n}{n^2}+\frac{h\log n}n$$

and since

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log n}{n^2}\;\;\;\text{converges but}\;\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{h\log n}n\;\;\;\text{diverges}$$

the right side as a whole diverges and thus the comparison test gives us our series diverges, too.